# How can I secure the power block for my LED headlights?

Tags: subaru, headlight, forester, led

I purchased an [LED low-beam conversion kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00T1718JU) and installed it yesterday in my 2010 Forester.  The installation was easy enough, other than having to move the battery to get enough space to fit my headlight.

However, I am not sure whether I've done an adequate job attaching the ballasts (the square-ish metal bricks that convert the regular headlight power connection, and limit the current, to what the LED lights need).  I read [this Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Convert-Your-Headlight-Bulbs-to-LED/?ALLSTEPS) which recommended double-stick-tape, which I used - but I'm not convinced this is going to hold for years.

Is double-stick-tape a secure way to mount this?  Is there a better option that I would have at home (I'm at the 'change oil and headlights' level of mechanical ability with cars, but not beyond that)?  Should I ask my mechanic next time I take it in for something else to attach it better?

If relevant, both ballasts are currently secured to a metal part of the frame, below the headlights.  The Forester has tiny dust covers behind the headlight bulbs (just round caps maybe 5" diameter and less than an inch tall) which I'm not able to use because the bulb (with the heat sink) is too long, so I can't attach to those like the Instructable recommends.

Comment: I tried to install resistors for LED turn signals with double stick tape, and it didn't even hold that with the heat of the engine and the resistor.  Maybe it depends on the tape you use, but I had quality 3M mounting tape...

Comment: Is there anything you can get a cable tie around? Any electrical store will sell outdoor rated ties for small change.

Comment: @Sam The left headlight seems more likely than the right headlight there.  The left headlight has a couple of tube-shaped things in the area - the wiper fluid, the oil dipstick, etc. - which might be close enough and not have too much vibration.  Right headlight area is a bit less clear - I'd have to look.  That's near the radiator (which I assume gets too hot to want to attach to?) and the air ducts, which are too wide I think.  I'll take a peek.  Also - you might want to post that as an answer, as even if it doesn't work for me it might work for others :)

Comment: Zip ties are your friend ... :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pictured tape, or any double sided tape for that matter, will fail quickly. Even the industrial 3M VHB tape isn't worth spit, under the hood.

Zip tie or find a natural crevice for it if possible and the leads are long enough.